# Ошибка ModuleNotFound при установке buildozer

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy

Пытаюсь установить `buildozer`. Выполнил следующие команды:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
```

При попытке выполнения `sudo python3 setup.py install` выдаёт  `No Module named Setuptools`
При вводе `python3 -m pip install setuptools` говорит, что модуль уже установлен

Comment: pip3 install buildozer?

Comment: Попробуйте команду
`sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`